# Parse JSON response from Servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

Ok, Ive got a Java Servlet returning some JSON (In Application/JSON format). To do this, im using the GSON libary.

The Servlets GET method takes one paramater, ID. The servlet seems to be working, For example,chrome shows my AJAX GET request returning the following when the [Booking]ID paramater sent is 1.

```
    0: {WidgetID:46, BookingID:1, X:393, Y:50, Content:Test1}
    1: {WidgetID:47, BookingID:1, X:337, Y:251, Content:Test2}
    2: {WidgetID:48, BookingID:1, X:97, Y:198, Content:Test3}
```

The problem I have is with parsing this response. Here is my JS code:

> ```
>     loadPositions() {
>     var BookingID = 
>     if (BookingID != null && BookingID != "null")
>     {
>     var data = {"id" : BookingID};
>     $.getJSON("Widget", data, function(data) {
>     // Successfully got all this bookings widgets as JSON, TODO: Parse this!
>     });
>     }
>     }
> ```

What should I put in the "TODO: Parse this!" section?
I want to foreach over all the elements, and grab their data. I really suck at this JQuery stuff.

Comment: Run your JSON through http://jsonlint.com/ - is it valid?

Comment: I wouldn't think so: JSON requires keys to be strings, surrounded by double quotes, and values to be ints or, again, double quote surrounded strings.

Comment: I think JQuery is mangling my JSON? As if I go to http://localhost:8080/BookingSystem/Widget?id=1 in my browser, I get different (valid) JSON : [{"WidgetID":46,"BookingID":1,"X":393,"Y":50,"Content":"Test1"},{"WidgetID":47,"BookingID":1,"X":337,"Y":251,"Content":"Test2"},{"WidgetID":48,"BookingID":1,"X":97,"Y":198,"Content":"Test3"}]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the todo section, you should do the following to loop through all the arrays:

```
$.each(data, function(index,value){
    // here index=0 & value.WidgetID=46, value.BookingId = 1, use it as you would like to.

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at jQuery .each()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

and for a good example of what you want to do...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

https://github.com/acobley/jBoggyAppy/blob/HectorV2-Cassandra-0.7.0/WebContent/Scripts/index.js

the ShowScrollingTags function.